# Aggregate to find the weighted median

Tags: r, aggregate, weighted-average

I have the following data set:

```
df <- data.frame(
  C      = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1),
  weight = c(1,1.5,2,2,1.5,1,2,1,1.5,2.5),
  time   = c(15,20,30,45,60,15,20,30,45,60)
)
```

I need to aggregate the data by the variable C in order to find the median time for each C. Each observation is weighted by the variable 'weight'.

Is there a way to replace 'mean' by a weighted median in the following code ?

```
output<-aggregate(.~C, data=df, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a weighted median function in the `bigvis` package on github.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("bigvis")
```

`aggregate` doesn't work with functions that need multiple vector inputs.  Use `ddply` from `plyr` instead.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(C), summarise, wm = weighted.median(time, weight))
```

Comment: When trying to install bigvis I get the following error:    Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: github.com; Host not found

Comment: @user2568648 Are you on a corporate network?  If so, the most likely explanation is that access to github is blocked by your network admins.  Try and reach the site in a browser.